# Making aggregateTemplate dynamic In ng-grid

Tags: ng-grid

I am facing an issue in making my aggregateTemplate dynamic, i.e.; I want to change my aggregate template on button click.
I have replicated my code on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/txoPNF?p=preview